# How to query in manytomany relation in django

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have following tables in django:

```
class foroccasion(models.Model):
        occasions=models.CharField(max_length=2000)
    def __unicode__(self):
            return self.occasions

class forstyle(models.Model):
        style=models.CharField(max_length=2000)
    def __unicode__(self):
            return self.style

class forbodytype(models.Model):
        bodytype=models.CharField(max_length=2000)
    def __unicode__(self):
            return self.bodytype

class  Input(models.Model):
    apparelid=models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    userid=models.CharField(max_length=140)
    occassion=models.ManyToManyField(foroccasion)
    bodytype=models.ManyToManyField(forbodytype)
    style=models.ManyToManyField(forstyle)
    rating=models.IntegerField(default=100)
        def __unicode__(self):
            return self.userid
```

Now i have some values already present in database;
suppose i have rectangle,peer,circle stored in my table bodytype 
now i need to extract all those input objects for which bodytype is rectangle.please help me with this ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a shot.

```
Input.objects.filter(bodytype__bodytype = 'rectangle')
```

Comment: Without the quotes, though.

Comment: thnx it helps me but what should i do if i need to find all the bodytypes of a specific user id .....